# Angular 5.0.0 HttpClient doesn't send Headers on POST

Tags: angular5

When I send a GET with HttpClient, server receives the Authorization Header. But when I send the same request using POST, Angular doesn't send the **Authorization** Header.

```
let cabecalho1 = new HttpHeaders();

cabecalho1 = cabecalho1.append("Authorization", "Basic YXBpOmViYzg3Njg5MjhiZjkljjE1NGIyMTg4NGZlMjU5MDA3NDllMGU0MTRmZGM");
cabecalho1 = cabecalho1.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

let url = "http://localhost/ionic/json.php";

// 'post' doesn't sends Authorization Header.
// when I change to 'get' verb, the server receives the Authorization Header.
this.httpClient.post(url, 
  {
    headers: cabecalho1,

    params: {
      ola: 'mundo',
      cnt: '5'
    }
  }).subscribe(res => {
    // this.posts = res;
    console.log("resposta POST:");
    console.log(res);
  });
```

**Comparing POST vs GET data sent (in Yellow is the GET)**

[image: In YELLOW, The GET sent the Authorization]

When I use Postman, the Authorization Header is received both in GET and POST in my PHP server.
Why Angular 5 HttpClient **doesn't** send Authorization Header  specifically in POST?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the reference for HttpClient [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient), you'll see that the signature for get() is this:

```
get(
    url: string,
    options: 
        { 
            headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; 
            observe?: HttpObserve; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; };
            reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "text" | "json"; withCredentials?: boolean;
        } = {}
 ): Observable<any>
```

and the signature for post() is this:

```
post(
    url: string,
    body: any,
    options:
        {
            headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };
            observe?: HttpObserve; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; };
            reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "text" | "json";
            withCredentials?: boolean;
        } = {}
): Observable<any>
```

as you can see, the "body" parameter of the post() method is not optional (because it does not have a '?' immediately after it), therefore is required. You *were* sending your headers, but they were in the body of the post request, rendering them useless.

To fix this, add an empty object for the "body" parameter, like so:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, {},
  {
    headers: cabecalho1,

    params: {
             ola: 'mundo',
             cnt: '5'
  }
}).subscribe(res => {
    // 
});
```

Comment: Wow! that extra {} helps! Thank you!!! I have been struggling with my angular 8 Post not sending Authorization and could not figure out why. Apparently there is a body: any that is not optional. Thank you 4dc0!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  myApiFunction(id: string) {

    // add authorization header with jwt token
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token });
    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'https://213.121.21.21/api/myApiFunction', id , options);
  }
```